# `make` compilation for OpenGL works on VSCode's terminal, but gives `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` on regular terminal (macOS M1)

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, clang, apple-m1

OS: macOS Ventura version `13.1`, on M1.

I'm compiling a simple OpenGL program. I have a `makefile` as shown below:

```
CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib -w
LIBS = -lGLEW.2.2.0 -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT

SOURCES = t2.cpp
OBJ = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TARGETS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=)

all: $(TARGETS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(TARGETS): %: %.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(TARGETS) *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

My simple `t2.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void resizeCB(int width, int height)
{
    /* use the full view port */
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    /* use 2D  orthographic parallel projection  */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, width, 0.0, height);
}

typedef struct point2D
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point2D;

Point2D roof[3];
Point2D house[4];

void initGeom()
{
    // initialize the roof
    roof[0].x = 270;
    roof[0].y = 340;
    roof[1].x = 450;
    roof[1].y = 340;
    roof[2].x = 360;
    roof[2].y = 400;
    house[0].x = 285;
    house[0].y = 270;
    house[1].x = 435;
    house[1].y = 270;
    house[2].x = 435;
    house[2].y = 340;
    house[3].x = 285;
    house[3].y = 340;
}

// clear the window and fill it with white colour
// set up gl colour to white
void renderCB()
{
    // glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    // clearing up the canvas with the specific colour
    initGeom();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // swap the buffers (using double buffers

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        glVertex2iv((GLint *)&roof[i]);
    }

    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        glVertex2iv((GLint *)&house[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    // return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int winId;
    // initialize GLUT and pass it the command variables
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    winId = glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 02");
    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("Error - %s \n", glewGetErrorString(res));
        return (-1);
    }
    // print OpenGL information
    printf("Renderer: %s \n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("OpenGL version: %s \n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("OpenGL shading language version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
    glutReshapeFunc(resizeCB);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderCB);
    glutMainLoop();
    return (0);
}
```

I've noticed that when I compile via `make` on VSCode's integrated terminal, it works, output:

```bash
clang++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib -w -c -o t2.o t2.cpp
clang++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib -w -o t2 t2.o -lGLEW.2.2.0 -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
```

But, when I compile via `make` on a regular terminal, I get this:

```bash
clang++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib -w -c -o t2.o t2.cpp
clang++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib -w -o t2 t2.o -lGLEW.2.2.0 -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glewGetErrorString", referenced from:
      _main in t2.o
  "_glewInit", referenced from:
      _main in t2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [t2] Error 1
```

I'm honestly stumped as to why. I've restarted my computer, and now everything works as expected. WHAT???

I mean, I was expecting `make` to be deterministic across both terminals. I can't say I've tried anything meaningful aside from restarting my computer, I'm quite confused as to discrepancies -- this is probably the first I've encountered such a bug. I'm not sure if I'll encounter such a bug again, but I do not want to restart my computer as a fix -- and I want to understand why this is happening.

My best (terrible) guess has something to do with VSCode's terminal makefile invoking the `arm64-apple-darwin<version>` clang++ binary, but the regular terminal's makefile invoked the `x86_64-apple-darwin<version>` clang++ binary.

But I can't for the life of me figure out why, as the makefile does not ever specify the architecture, and would assume the default (ARM).

I want to get to the bottom of this, this is one really interesting bug. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could always inject some logging into your makefile to test your hypothesis.

Comment: If your IDE is running in Rosetta, then anything it spawns will run in Rosetta by default. But unrelated, if an issue like this goes away after a reboot, I would assume it's a `$PATH` issue or something related.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, one has to check the running architectures on both VS Code integrated and Apple Terminal, e.g.:

[image]

[image]

I had a similar issue, and I ended up with the following conclusion:

This likely happened because of a transfer (migration) e.g.: all apps and settings from an Old MacBookPro (Intel i5-based) to a brand-new MacBookPro, based on Apple Silicon M1. As a consequence, the transferred VS Code version is Intel-based,
[image]

which of course runs well, due to the Rosetta layer. Thus, when we open a new integrated terminal in VS Code, it defaults to x86-64 (i386) architecture.

That means that the compilation behaves OK inside the VS Code integrated terminal possibly because the libraries used are either x86-64 or universal ones. But when we open a new Apple terminal it defaults to arm64 architecture.

You can change the terminal architecture by using:

`$ exec arch -x86_64 $SHELL`

or

`$ exec arch -arm64 $SHELL`

respectively.

I hope this can help.